# Finding limits by interpreting a graph

Tags: calculus, limits

**Am I doing these limit problems correctly?** It almost seems to simple, so I wanted to double check. For *f.,* do I find the limit as x approaches -3 from the *right* or from the *left*?

If it is from the right, the limit as x approaches -3 would be 0
If it is from the left, the limit as x approaches -3 would be -2.

[image]

Comment: Your reasoning for $f.$ seems fine.

Comment: @mvw Thanks. Do the rest of them seem fine as well?

Comment: Looks good as well.